# Angular 2 - changes values from a parent component not reflecting in ngIf statement even though the child component actually gets the form

Tags: javascript, angular, components, angular-ng-if

here is the parent component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
 selector: 'app-bukkacorporateform',
  templateUrl: './bukkacorporateform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bukkacorporateform.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class BukkacorporateformComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
check: number = 6;

indi = function individual(){
    this.check = 4;
}
cliq = function clique(){
    this.check = 5;
}

comp = function company(){
    this.check = 6;
}
```

}

and here is the child component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from         '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {FormService} from '../../services/form.service';
import {CompaniesData} from '../../models/companies-data';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-corporateform',
  templateUrl: './corporateform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./corporateform.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [FormService]
})
export class CorporateformComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('data') type:number;
  value: boolean = true;
  subscriptionForm : FormGroup;
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private formService: FormService){
    this.subscriptionForm = fb.group({
      'contactname' : '',
      'phonenumber': '',
      'type' : '',
      'email' : '',
      'companyname' : '',
      'approxbudget' : '',
      'approxbudget' : '',
      'noofpeople' : '',
      'eventtype': ''
    })
  }
  submitForm(value: any):void{
    value.type = this.type;
    value.phonenumber += '';
    value.phonenumber = '0' + value.phonenumber;
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

when i submit the form the type variable is actually changing as expected, however the ngIf in the view is not responding to the same variable changes
and in the template

```
<div class="three-in" *ngIf="type == 6">
                <!--<div class="form-group col-3 drop_fields">
                </div>-->
                <div class="form-group col-3">
                <input class="form-control"   id="corporate_lead_event_at" name="corporate_lead[event_at]" placeholder="Date of event" readonly="readonly" style="background-color: #fff;" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-3">
                  <input class="form-control" data-error="Invalid number" data-wrong="Invalid number" id="corporate_lead_budget" name="corporate_lead[budget]" placeholder="Approx Budget" type="number">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-3">
                  <input class="form-control" id="corporate_lead_number_of_people" name="corporate_lead[number_of_people]" placeholder="No. of people" type="number">
                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Include your template in your question.

Comment: i have added the view now

Comment: Where are you updating `type` ?

Comment: How is the `BukkacorporateformComponent` related to your question?

Comment: it is the parent component where the actual variable changes occur, via the this.check if statements the check variable is pushed to type via the @Input angular implementation